# What's the difference in performance between foreach and the alternative syntax in php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, foreach

I'm trying to display an array of more than 5000 items in HTML view with foreach alternative syntax in php and it doesn't work but, with the basic syntax, i don't have problem.

I tried to display a list of items with foreach alternative syntax from php.
i tried with 2000, 2200, ... value until 2400 values and it works correctly.
Over 2400 values, my page process until a timeout exception.

With the basic syntax, it works even with more than 6000 items.

Why there is a difference between those 2 syntax.

alternative syntax :

```html
<table>
...
   <?php foreach ($list as $val): ?>
     <tr role="row">
        <td><?= $val->id ?></td>
        <td>
        <?php if($val->status == "CONFIRMED"): ?>
           confirmed
        <?php else: ?>
           unconfirmed
        <?php endif ?>
        </td>
     </tr>
   <?php endforeach ?>
...
</table>
```

basic syntax :

```html
<table>
...
<?php
foreach ($list as $val){
   echo '<tr role="row">';
   echo '<td>' . $val->id . '</td>';
   echo '<td>';
   if($val->status == "CONFIRMED"){
        echo 'confirmed';
   }else{
        echo 'unconfirmed';
   }
   echo '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
?>
...
</table>
```

thanks for your answers.

the code with the alternative syntax never finish when the array contain more than 2500 items.
the basic syntax works without any problem.

Comment: Good question - I have no idea, I hope someone else does.

Comment: If I were you I would create two scripts, profile them both, then check out what each one is doing with webgrind.  https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind

Comment: The scripts are quite different, I would try the first one using braces - i.e. `<?php foreach ($list as $val){ ?>` and `<?php } ?>`